# react-native all commands failing

Tags: react-native

I tried upgrading react-native in a seperate branch and it caused some issues, so i reset everything and abandoned the branch. Currently on version:     `"react-native": "0.59.9",`

Now when I try and run any command with `react-native` including `react-native info` I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../tools/PackageManager'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/_name_/solo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/install/install.js:10:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I tried several node versions using NVM.
Currently on 10.16.0 of node.
`react-native` appears to be working correctly when I create a new project and run commands

I have tried blowing away node_modules and package-json, locking down all versions of libraries, still no luck.

Comment: If you can create new projects, how about copying the source files from the problematic one to a new one?

Comment: potentially a fix but i've done this 10 or 12 times throughout the course of this project and would love to have just a normal fix

Comment: There is no `react-native info` command in React-native.

Comment: You can try install `npm install rnpm -g`

Comment: Happens with all react native commands

Answer (score 1):

Seems it coudn't find the npm. Can you check the npm it is working in the same workspace and try to reinstall the react native commands with the same npm.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```